# How do you make a Caption Less Window in Gtk?

Tags: c#, c, gtk, gtk#

I want to make a Window in Gtk (Gtk# to be specific, but GTK+ or any other binding will do, the functions are generally the same) without a caption. Kind of like Mozilla Firefox 4 and Google Chrome. I don't know what to call it, caption less or widget on caption? Any Help? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term is 'decorated'.

In plain GTK+, this is `gtk_window_set_decorated()` and in GTK#, do `this.Decorated = false;` in your forms constructor, that's all.

Note that decoration is not only the title bar but also the frame that allows for resizing. There is unfortunately no way to have a resizable but title-bar-less window, you will have to handle border mouse-over-detection and resizing yourself.

Comment: And, note that this function only hints the window manager to supress the decorations on the window, it's up to the window manager implementation respect or not the hints the window is providing.

Comment: Also, note that in this mechanism are involved a bunch of libraries/system. The Gtk+ backend is involved, and has to support this kind of operation.